# Does have been used correctly here

Tags: grammaticality, tense

I would like to use have been in my sentence in order to explain that a specific method has been done. However, I do not know whether I used "has been" correctly or not?

Here is my sentence:

> Later, several works **have been** introduced this model into a finite mixture model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your question should be (Is/Was 'has been' used correctly here?)
2. Has been introduced/done. Is passive. We use the passive voice when the subject is unknown or unimportant. As in your question, Is 'has been' used correctly (by you).

   - You/someone has used/has introduced a specific method. (Active)
   - A specific method has been used/has been introduced by you/by someone. (Passive)

In your sentence, 'Several works' seems to be the subject. If it is, then your sentence is incorrect. It should be: Later, several works have introduced this model as a finite mixture model.
If 'several works' isn't the subject (the person or thing that does the action) then perhaps it should be: Later, this model has been introduced in several works as a finite mixture model. 
I have to be sure who or what does or receives the action to tell you what your sentence should be.

Comment: There is a specific method which has been introduced into finite mixture model by several searchers. Hence, I would like to say that this method was introduced into finite mixture model by several works.

Comment: You can say: Several researches have introduced this model as a finite mixture model. (Active) Or: This model has been introduced as a finite mixture model in several researches.(Passive)